# JsonObj.getString(key) returning 0 instead of 0000

Tags: android, json

I have an simple json string

```
{"username":"myemail@play.co.in","password":"0000"}
```

When I tried to read the json string using following code

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
 Log.i(TAG,"uname "+json.getString("username"));
 Log.i(TAG,"password "+json.getString("password"));
```

> Password printing as "password 0"   instead of "password 0000".

Please help me regarding this how can I read string instead of value.

Comment: Use it as a json string not an integer. Just put them in "double quotes"  "password":"0000"

Comment: Yup, 0000 = 0; left most zeroes are ignored

Comment: Write your two log results.

Comment: your json is not valid json.

Comment: I updated proper JSON string. I am calling jsonObj.getString(password) still it is returning 0.

Comment: This is odd. I created a simple activity which has your codes, and was able to print out 0000 properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value is being returned as an int. therefore the the leading 000 are cut out, essntially the same thing if you had an int 000009 returned in the json it would be converted to 9! if you want to get all chars surround the value element with quotes like this "0000". that way you will be returned all characters.

Comment: yes. inverted commas or quotations. personally. i would have called them chazzwazzers.

Comment: But i am calling as jsonObj.getString(password) and i updated the Json String.

Comment: yes, if you want to get a String it has to be a string e.g surrounded with inverted commas.

Comment: If i specify "password":”0000” in inverted commas the value it is priting with inverted commas. But i need only value. I/TAG: password ”0000”